# c# Draw from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I am making simple game (c# Win Forms) where my character moves on key events (arrows).

Main class:

```
switch(e.Keycode)
{
    case Keys.Left:
    creature.moveleft(this,speed);
}
```

My Creature class looks like this:

```
public void Left(object sender,int speed)
{
    Form form = (Form)sender;

     Graphics grp = form.CreateGraphics();
    ..
    ..
    ..
}
```

I don't like that I have to pass `this` every time I want to draw something. I ended up having `Form form=(Form)sender` for every draw method in Creature class.

Is there a better way to do it?

I thought that if I inherit from `Form` in my Creature class and than use `Graphics grp=this.CreateGraphics` would work but it actually doesn't draw anything.

Thanks

Comment: `CreateGraphics` makes a temporary drawing surface, which is likely being erased before you even see it.  Poor choice of methodology.  Draw in the form itself using the form's `Paint` method.

Answer (score 0):

If your Creature class is created after the form is created, why not just pass the form as a parameter to the constructor, eg:

```
public class Creature
{
    private Form form;

    public Creature(Form form)
    {
        this.form = form;
    }

    ...

    public void Left(int speed)
    {
        Graphics grp = form.CreateGraphics();
        ..
        ..
        ..
    }
}
```

Comment: Word of advice:  if you intend to draw on a form, do it in the form using the `Paint` event.  `CreateGraphics` is always a poor choice.

Comment: that is correct, but a much bigger question to answer!

Comment: @ DonBoitnott @Chris Ballard So what would be the proper way of doing it using Paint event? And why is CreateGraphics poor choice? Thanks

Comment: @ DonBoitnott Could you show me an example of how to do this using paint event? thanks

Comment: It's a huge topic. I can only suggest you look for articles on implementing a 2D game in WinForms. It centres around drawing everything in OnPaint, and invalidating regions when things move.

Comment: However you'll run into issues with performance, so need to understand the minimal things to redraw, handing double buffering etc. A good article or perhaps a book would explain this.

Comment: @ Chris Ballard thanks for suggestions, I am invalidating only Creature rectangle. Everything is working just fine except that  Form form= (Form) sender is ugly.

Comment: well the above code should help with that, but bear in mind the other suggestions when you see weird redraw problems when moving other windows in front of yours etc

Comment: @ Chris Ballard got one more question. if I use public Creature(Form form)
    {
        this.form = form;
    } how would I create instance of creature? (this keyword doesn't work) Thanks

Comment: Where do you create the Creature? If (I'm guessing here) it is in the Form `OnLoad` handler, just do `Creature blah = new Creature(this)`